# How can I correctly setup this nested association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```
class MealPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_contents
  has_many :foods,:through => :food_contents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_contents
  attr_accessible :food_contents_attributes,:name
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name,:protein,:carbs,:fats,:calories
  validates_numericality_of :protein,:carbs,:fats,:calories
end

class FoodContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal_plan
  belongs_to :food

  attr_accessible :food_id, :how_much,:meal_plan_id
  validates_presence_of :food,:meal_plan
end
```

I have the following code in the meal plan controller:

```
  def new
    @meal_plan = MealPlan.new
    3.times { @meal_plan.food_contents.build }
  end


def create
  @meal_plan = MealPlan.new(params[:meal_plan])
end
```

and the following form for a meal plan:

```
<%= form_for(@meal_plan) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :food_contents do |b| %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>New food</legend>
      <%= b.collection_select :food_id,Food.all,:id,:name,{},{:class => "food_id_selector"} %><br/>
      <%= b.text_field :how_much,:class => "how_much_input" %><br/>
      <%= content_tag(:p,nil,:class => "food_acumulator") %>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, when it always fails to save the model, with the error:

```
> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xb34212e8
 @base=#<MealPlan id: nil, name: "Sample", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 @messages={:"food_contents.meal_plan"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

From what I've debugged, the culprit is `validates_presence_of :meal_plan` from:

```
class FoodContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  ...
  validates_presence_of :food,:meal_plan
end
```

On one side, I can understand why it cannot save the nested models ( since the meal plan does not have an id yet ), but on the other side, I want to make sure that what I'm doing is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fiddled around a bit and found a way you can save your three models by skipping the validation on meal_plan:

```
mp = MealPlan.new
fc = mp.food_contents.build
f = fc.build_food
f.save
mp.save(validate: false)
fc.save
```

which shouldn't be an issue, as it is validated again when fc is saved, which you can verify by this:

```
mp = MealPlan.new
fc = mp.food_contents.build
f = fc.build_food
f.save
mp.save(validate: false)
fc.food = nil
fc.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered already, but a much simpler way to do this without saving without validation is to simply set the id = 1. This way, the validation for the id passes and when the records are written to the database, the ids will be overwritten with the correct ones.

so you can simply do something like:

```
@mp = MealPlan.new(your_strong_param_access_function) # all ur nested stuff should then be automatically pulled into mp including your associations.
@mp.food_contents.each do |fc|
  fc.meal_plan_id = 1
end
@mp.save
```

That's it. the validation won't fail because meal_plan_id is set to 1.
and when active record saves everything, it will update meal_plan_id to the correct value.
and all ur other validations are still actively working :)